# Use a subqueries field data to format a condition in the same query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm wondering if this is possible, haven't found any documentation on it so I thought I would ask.

What I am wanting to do, to prevent running multiple queries is to get a value from one query and use that value to select a database and join other values to the original.

In this situation, I am getting the users state and joining their "plans" table on their id. Based on the state of the individual I want to access that states "plans" database and join it to the results. Something like this... but I know my code is not correct.

```
SELECT * FROM state.'Company_Plans' AS C 
WHERE (SELECT company_id,user_id,user_state AS state 
    FROM user.'address_info' AS A 
    INNER JOIN user.'plan_info' AS B ON A.user_id = B.user_id ) 
WHERE C.company_id = B.company_id
```

Any help would be nice. Thank you.

Comment: Yes and No. You could join to all of the tables in other databases, then use a case or if function to select the correct db.table.columns. This would probably bring tears to your server though. You will not be able to substitute a db name (or table name) for that matter directly in the query. You might be able to create a stored function that creates the SQL statement then executes it. But if you will return multiple rows that match multiple DBs, you are in for a difficult time.

Comment: One possibility would be to create views to the tables in the other DBs in the DB where you would execute this query. If you are in the US, and have 50 DBs, you might want to hunt down the person who designed the data structure and beat them with a stick.

Comment: They should have read up on normalization....

Comment: Yeah it would be much better if all the states plans were in one database/table. Iv already beaten him multiple times lol.